# Messing labels colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, label

I'm plotting data from a dict which has three keys:

```
[u'Ferronikel', u'Nicromo', u'Alambre_1']
```

And each one of this have several params like resistances, voltage an a like
so I'm using a function to plot the values easily.

```
def graficar_parametro(x,y):

    d_unidades = {'I':'A','V':'V','R':'ohm','T':'C','P':'W/m'}
    for alambre in sorted(alambres.keys()):
        model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()


        X = alambres[alambre]['mediciones'][x].reshape(-1, 1)
        Y = alambres[alambre]['mediciones'][y].reshape(-1, 1)
        model.fit(X,Y)


        x_label = d_unidades[x]
        y_label = d_unidades[y]
        plt.legend(sorted(alambres.keys()))
        plt.xlabel(x_label)
        plt.ylabel(y_label)
        plt.plot(X,Y,'8',
                X, model.predict(X),'-')
    plt.title('Heating wires')

    plt.show()
```

To plot Voltage vs current I run:

```
graficar_parametro('I','V')
```

And got this images:

[image]

But there the colors are wrong:

Blue dots correspond to 'Alambre_1' that one is fine, but   yellow dots should  be labeled as 'Nicromo' and ferronikel should have the red dots not a green line.

I thought to use `sorted` would solve the issue, but it doesn't fix it.

```
for alambre in sorted(alambres.keys()):
       plt.legend(sorted(alambres.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do so is to make storage for matplotlib objects. And you need to distinguish dot- and line-plots.

```
def graficar_parametro(x,y):

d_unidades = {'I':'A','V':'V','R':'ohm','T':'C','P':'W/m'}
leg = [] # Storage for plots we want to legend
for alambre in sorted(alambres.keys()):
    model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()


    X = alambres[alambre]['mediciones'][x].reshape(-1, 1)
    Y = alambres[alambre]['mediciones'][y].reshape(-1, 1)
    model.fit(X,Y)


    x_label = d_unidades[x]
    y_label = d_unidades[y]

    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    dots, = plt.plot(X,Y,'8')
    line, = plt.plot(X, model.predict(X),'-')
    leg.append(line) # Choose what symbols will be represented in legend
plt.legend(leg, sorted(alambres.keys())) # Legend
plt.title('Heating wires')

plt.show()
```

If you want that both dots and lines were represented in legend, append to `leg` like this:

```
leg.append((dots, line))
```

Comment: what does the ',' stand for in 'line, ?

Comment: `plt.plot(X, model.predict(X),'-')` is an array with one Line2D element. You just unpacking this array, so that `line =  Line2D.object`.